# Sign in with Apple not working with Firebase/Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project where I have enabled authentication via Google, Microsoft and recently I added Apple. Both Google and Microsoft work correctly, but Apple login is throwing an error.  I have ensured I have Apple Signin enabled and I've configured Sign in with Apple on my Apple developer account.

[image]

Below is the code used to invoke it.

```
  static Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
    final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();

      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
     ]
      return userCredential;
  }
```

When I click to sign in with Apple, however, I get the following error:

**[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ Code flow is not enabled for Apple. ]**

As you can see from the picture, it IS enabled. I've also tried downloading the latest google-service.json file, and this has no impact.

Why does Firebase think it's disabled??

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the requirements which is written on firebase website

**Important: To sign in with an Apple account, users must:**

- Have an Apple ID with two-factor authentication (2FA) enabled.
- Be signed in to iCloud on an Apple device.

docs : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple#configure-sign-in-with-apple

Comment: Good point...I was using my appleID on web signing in, so I assumed you could use any device, but I guess it's only allowed on an apple device.

Comment: even you cannot you apple sign-in on android device.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the same issue encountered on both Web and Android platforms, it's necessary to complete the "OAuth code flow configuration (optional)" step. Here's a streamlined guide:

1. Begin by creating a key at Apple's Developer site: [Apple Developer Account - Authentication Keys](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list).
2. Navigate to your Firebase project's configuration for Apple sign-in:

   - Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-name/authentication/providers).
   - Access the 'Authentication' section.
   - Choose 'Sign-in Method'.
   - Select 'Sign-in Providers'.
   - Click on 'Apple'.
   - Proceed to 'OAuth code flow configuration (optional)'.
3. Here, you'll need to provide specific details: your Team ID, Key ID, and the Private key.
4. For a detailed walkthrough, refer to step 4 in the Fireship tutorial video titled "Sign in with Apple from a Firebase Web App" available on YouTube: [Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UafqYgRoIC0&t=59s).

This guide should help you effectively configure OAuth code flow for Apple sign-in within your Firebase project.